# pivot data from csv and store in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, data-science

I have a requirement such that :

i have a csv file with following data (this is just example, data is much larger):

```
xxxx|A|B|C|D|E
xxxx|P|Q|R|S|T
DATE|L|M|N|O|P
01/02/1997|12|4|5|0|0
01/03/1998|71|2|4|8|0
```

i want to save the data in a data frame such that the columns should be :

```
 A   01/02/1997   P   L  12
 B   01/02/1997   Q   M   4
 C   01/02/1997   R   N   5
 D   01/02/1997   S   O   0
 E   01/02/1997   T   P   0
 A   01/03/1998   P   L  71
 B   01/03/1998   Q   M   2
 C   01/03/1998   R   N   4
 D   01/03/1998   S   O   8
 E   01/03/1998   T   P   0
```

basically first column should be pivoted . can anyone help? the names and data are just examples(dummy)

Comment: `pd.read_clipboard(header=[0,1,2], sep='|').set_index(['xxxx']).unstack().reset_index()`

Comment: The way to do is, know which row is header, and which column is index, set them, then `unstack` or `stack` depends on what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create `MultiIndex in columns` by `header=[0,1,2]` parameter and convert first column to index by `index_col=[0]` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="|", header=[0,1,2], index_col=[0])
print (df)
xxxx         A  B  C  D  E
xxxx         P  Q  R  S  T
DATE         L  M  N  O  P
01/02/1997  12  4  5  0  0
01/03/1998  71  2  4  8  0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('A', 'P', 'L'),
            ('B', 'Q', 'M'),
            ('C', 'R', 'N'),
            ('D', 'S', 'O'),
            ('E', 'T', 'P')],
           names=['xxxx', 'xxxx', 'DATE'])
```

Then transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), sort by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), create labels for MultiIndex by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and last convert `MultiIndex Series` to `DataFrame` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = (df.T
         .stack(dropna=False)
         .sort_index(level=3)
         .rename_axis(('a','b','c','d'))
         .reset_index(name='e'))
print (df1)
   a  b  c           d   e
0  A  P  L  01/02/1997  12
1  B  Q  M  01/02/1997   4
2  C  R  N  01/02/1997   5
3  D  S  O  01/02/1997   0
4  E  T  P  01/02/1997   0
5  A  P  L  01/03/1998  71
6  B  Q  M  01/03/1998   2
7  C  R  N  01/03/1998   4
8  D  S  O  01/03/1998   8
9  E  T  P  01/03/1998   0
```

Comment: Thing is i just gave it as an example and the column numbers are unknown like currently in this example i have provided only 5 columns abcde but they can be more with different names so cant really form a multiindex

Comment: @ayushgupta - Do you think number of levels is unknown? here are 3 levels in sample data `A  B  C  D  E`, `P  Q  R  S  T`, `L  M  N  O  P`

Comment: no , number of level is fixed  i.e 3 as shown here . but the number of columns is not fixed

Comment: @ayushgupta - If header has same separator like data and laso same length, it working perfctly. There should be more values, still working very nice.

Comment: @ayushgupta - OK, if some error or problem let me know.

Comment: one more thing it is ignoring NA values . so the rows are less. What should i do if i wanna consider them too ?

Comment: the solution seems to be working but the NA values are being ignored . Is there any sol for that

Comment: @ayushgupta - only change `.stack()` to `.stack(dropna=False)`, answer was edited.